# Prove polynomial inequality

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-optimization

I need to prove that a function f has a minimum, among convexity analysis I need to prove that

$f(x,y)≥2(x^2+y^2 )-2 \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}-8$

with

$f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2x^2+x+y-3$

EDIT

$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: what kind of numbers are $x,y$?

Comment: $(x,y) \in R^2$

Comment: The Question seems oddly worded, even with the Edit (thanks for that).  Showing that the function has "a minimum, among convexity analysis" is not obviously related to the inequality you "need to prove".  Should an Answer focus on that inequality?  Or on the existence of a minimum?

Comment: my bad, I wanted to prove the inequality. Once proven, that would allow me to say that $f$ is bounded thus the problem $inf f$ has a solution. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the result, I just had to start with the following inequality

$x+y > -2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$

and add polynomial terms in canonical form on the LHS.